# QGraphicsItem paint not called

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I use `QGraphicsView`, `QGrapichsScene` and `QGraphicsItem` for drawing some charts. I have implemented `QGraphicsItem::paint` function for drawing text (values of charts), but it is not being called every time that is must draw something new. My `paint` function

```
    void CLabelItem::paint(QPainter *painter, 
const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* /*option*/, QWidget* /*widget = 0*/)
{

    if ( GetValue() < 0 )
    {
        return;
    }
    painter->drawText(boundingRect(), m_value.toString());
}
```

So my question is - why `QGraphicsItem::paint` can be not called and how may I make it to be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `QGraphicsItem::update()` from the function that modify the `m_value` variable to trigger a repaint.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it worked! But now there is another problem - `QGraphicsItem::paint` is not being called for all items, although they all have correct bounding rects. Could you please help with that too?

Comment: @nabroyan Do the bounding rects of these items change between repaints ? Because you would need to call `prepareGeometryChange()` in that case (in addition to `update()`).

Comment: I got it, it was a mistake in counting bounding rect.

Answer (score 0):

In general with Qt graphics items are drawn when `paintEvent` is called, and then you can handle painting inside a `paint` function.